# Show in errors from API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am beginner web developer.

I make my first project in due and laravel 8.

My API return me error: {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"email":["Taki email ju\u017c wyst\u0119puje."], "login":["Taki login ju\u017c wyst\u0119puje."]}}

I have this code:

```
axios.post(this.$apiAdress + '/api/administrators?token=' + localStorage.getItem("api_token"),
        self.record
      )
        .then(function (response) {
          if (response.data.status == 'success') {
            Swal.fire(
              'Sukces',
              'Rekord dodany poprawnie!@',
              'success'
            )
          } else {
            Swal.fire(
              'Błąd',
              response,
              'error'
            )
          }
          this.$router.replace({path: '/administrators/create'});
        }).catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response.data.message == 'The given data was invalid.') {
          Swal.fire(
            'Błąd',
            'Proszę wypełnić wszystkie pola oznaczone gwiazdką!',
            'error'
          )
          window.scrollTo({top: 0});
        }
```

In linę: error.response.data.message I have this errors.

I need print errors in Swal:

```
Swal.fire(
                'Błąd',
                '.... Here errors ....',
                'error'
              )
```

For example:

```
Swal.fire(
                    'Błąd',
                    'Taki email ju\u017c wyst\u0119puje. <br/> Taki login ju\u017c wyst\u0119puje.',
                    'error'
                  )
```

How can I make it?

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate over the `errors` object:

```
if (error.response.data.message == 'The given data was invalid.') {
    let error_details = ""

    for (let key in error.response.data.errors) {
        error_details += `${error.response.data.errors[key]}<br/>`
    }

    Swal.fire(
        'Błąd',
         error_details,
        'error'
    )
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in this specific example:

```js
Swal.fire(
  'Błąd',
  error.response.data.email + "<br />" + error.response.data.login,
  'error'
)
```

Comment: I can't use this form: response.error.email because I don't know how many errors user can generated. Is possible make universal show this error from json: {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"email":["Taki email ju\u017c wyst\u0119puje."], "login":["Taki login ju\u017c wyst\u0119puje."]}} ?

Answer (score 0):

You're printing an entire object which results in this:

```
"[object Object]"
```

You need to get the property FROM the object.

```
response.error.email
// Taki email ju\u017c wyst\u0119puje. <br/> Taki login ju\u017c wyst\u0119puje.
```

Or to print the object as string:

```
JSON.stringify(response);
```

You can also get the specific errors.

```
var errors = JSON.parse('{"message":"' + response.message + '","errors":' + JSON.stringify(response.errors) + '}');
// Object { ... }
```

Comment: I can't use this form: response.error.email because I don't know how many errors user can generated. Is possible make universal show this error from json: {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"email":["Taki email ju\u017c wyst\u0119puje."], "login":["Taki login ju\u017c wyst\u0119puje."]}} ?

Comment: Yes it is, `JSON.stringify(response)`.

Comment: This return me: {"message":"Request failed with status code 422","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Request failed with status code 422\n at createError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n at settle (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:66:7)","config":{"transitional":{"silentJSONParsing":true,"forcedJSONParsing":true,"clarifyTimeoutError":false},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":... not error